# Sort Roman numerals in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql

How to sort Roman numerals in SQL server?

[image]

Comment: Might want to look [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/sorting-roman-numerals-qu-t1587337.html), it addresses `IX` specifically.

Comment: [Another link that may be of interest](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/roman-numerals-to-integers-and-vice-versa-in-sql).